# How to install Rust using power shell?

Tags: windows, rust, automation

I want to install rust automatically via command line on Windows. It doesn't matter if it's power shell or not but I think power shell is the easiest without having to install other stuff manually.

I found https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AppVeyorBYOC/1.0.170/Content/scripts%5CWindows%5Cinstall_rust.ps1 but at

```
 Add-SessionPath "$env:USERPROFILE\.cargo\bin"
```

it says that `Add-SessionPath` is a cmdlet that does not exist.

Comment: Why not just use `rustup` as described [here](https://forge.rust-lang.org/infra/other-installation-methods.html)? All you have to do is download the executable and run it. That's essentially what that PowerShell script is doing anyway.

Comment: @Herohtar I need unnatended install

Comment: All you need to do is run `./rustup-init.exe -y`. You can use other command line options if you need to configure things differently from the default values, but it's entirely unattended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same error. I changed that line to this and the script worked with **Powershell 7**.

```
$env:Path = "$env:USERPROFILE\.cargo\bin"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Make new environment variables available in the current PowerShell session:
function reload {
   foreach($level in "Machine","User") {
      [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariables($level).GetEnumerator() | % {
         # For Path variables, append the new values, if they're not already in there
         if($_.Name -match 'Path$') { 
            $_.Value = ($((Get-Content "Env:$($_.Name)") + ";$($_.Value)") -split ';' | Select -unique) -join ';'
         }
         $_
      } | Set-Content -Path { "Env:$($_.Name)" }
   }
}
Write-Host "Installing Rust..." -ForegroundColor Cyan
$exePath = "$env:TEMP\rustup-init.exe"

Write-Host "Downloading..."
(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://static.rust-lang.org/rustup/dist/x86_64-pc-windows-msvc/rustup-init.exe', $exePath)

Write-Host "Installing..."
cmd /c start /wait $exePath -y
Remove-Item $exePath

$addPath = "$env:USERPROFILE\.cargo\bin"
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable
     ($addPath, $env:Path, [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)

reload

cargo --version
rustup --version
rustc --version
```